# Locate nearby BloodBanks

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I could fetch the nearby hospital using the following code

```
private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=hospital");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "API");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}
```

Google nearby places API doesn't support blood bank as one of its type...so is there a way to get only the nearest blood bank?If so, could you please tell how..It will be a great help for my project...

Comment: Google doesn't have a type for every possible place type. If you can't get the information you want via the API, you'll have to build your own data set, or possibly find the data in other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source:  [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

If you look at the **Optional parameters** section, there is a parameter called `keyword`.

Use that parameter and remove `type` parameter from your `StringBuilder`.

`type` parameters value should be `blood bank`.

```
private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {
    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&keyword=bloodbank");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "API");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}
```

Comment: thank you..this worked fine.
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&ketword=blood bank"); .but there shouldnot be any space between bloodbank and the spelling is keyword not ketword

Comment: @th3pat31 welcome..your coded helped me...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyword instead type, there's somethings that don't have type, and Blood Bank is one. Or you can try to search for health and then in your code check if the have words like 'blood bank'.